# Excel Table to Word Document Macro

Tags: python, excel, vba, ms-word

I am making a macro to automate a report from Excel to a word document, I have done this before as a type of mail merge but I am having trouble grasping how to do this one. All of the rows and columns need to be in one report with varying numbers of items under each section. I am pretty sure I need to use an If..Then..Else but really struggling with the template too. [Here is an example of the Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW5n4.png)

[This is a sample of the template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6UmH.png)
`

I have been looking into different macro options for this, I am not opposed to using python if necessary but would really prefer a macro option. Thank you

Comment: There have been a lot of posts out there for (say) 25 years about what is often called "many to one mail merge" in Word. There are approaches ranging from "use mailmerge with a bunch of complicated field codes" via " use mailmerge with a suitable DATABASE field to "use my free one-many mailmerge addon" and so on. The expectation here is that you a) do whatever research is needed to come up with a solution to *your specific problem"* and then b) if you're still "stuck", post your code, preferably with enough info. to allow someone to have some chance of working out what might be wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

based on your excel table

```
Sub ExportToWord()

    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim wrdRange As Word.Range
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
    
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True
    
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add
    Set wrdRange = wrdDoc.Content
    wrdRange.InsertAfter "Eating To Do List" & vbCrLf
        
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        wrdRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, "A").Value & " --- " & Cells(i, "B").Value & vbCrLf & Cells(i, "C").Value & vbCrLf
    Next i
        
    wrdDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:="C:\path\to\folder\" & "Eating To Do List" & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
    wrdDoc.Close
    wrdApp.Quit
    
    Set wrdRange = Nothing
    Set wrdDoc = Nothing
    Set wrdApp = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Exported to Word successfully!"
    
End Sub
```